# Firefox SDK: Pagemod -> every video .mp4?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to use pagemod from the firefox addon sdk to implement a content script to ever video (.mp4) like `http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4` 
What selector do I have to use?

Comment: Try `pageMod.PageMod({  include: "*.mp4"` should work

Comment: tried this one before, dont work...

Comment: Try just a `*` see if that works than narrow down from there.